# postgresql. filter by intersection of array field values

Tags: sql, postgresql

My dataset is:

```
# select * from test;
   list   | locked
 ---------+--------
  {a,b,c} | t
  {f,g,h} | f
  {c,d,e} | f
```

I need to select locked=FALSE rows with list values not intersecting with any locked=TRUE row.

By now, I'm stuck with:

```
# SELECT * FROM test WHERE NOT locked and NOT list && (SELECT list FROM test WHERE locked);
  list   | locked
---------+--------
 {f,g,h} | f
 (1 row)
```

Works but looks overheaded by comparing each locked=TRUE row. I'm looking for a way to select aggregated set of all locked=TRUE list values and compare it once for each locked=FALSE row.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work correctly. If I understood you correctly, you are looking for something more efficient. If you are willing to create a new table, you could something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE locked(elem text PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO locked SELECT DISTINCT unnest(list) FROM test WHERE locked;
```

This table will contain all elements from all the lists from `test` that correspond to a locked state. I am using the `unnest` function to convert (what appears to be) `text[]` to a table of `text` so that I can apply `DISTINCT`.

Then you would use that table like so

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE NOT locked AND
      NOT exists(SELECT FROM locked WHERE elem=ANY (list));
```

Note the `NOT locked` condition in the last query is redundant, but it might improve the performance if you use it.

If you need even better performance, you might have to further normalize the table `test`.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But ti doesn't feet my needs. Locks mechanics means concurrency. My table should work as job queue where concurrent workers takes jobs by UPDATE row whith setting lock attribute and RETURNING * so other workers can't take it. Managing separate lock table is way more overhead then comparing each row in this case.